# SwiftUI Preview: Preview failed if Custom ButtonStyle is in other file

Tags: xcode, swiftui

My Custom ButtonStyle look like this.

```swift
struct DefaultButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                .fill(configuration.isPressed ? Color.black : Color.green)
            )
    }
}
```

Sample implementation of using custom button style.

```swift
Button(action: { self.viewModel.login() }) {
  Text("Sign In")
    .font(.headline)
}
.buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 380)
.padding([.leading, .trailing], 27.5)
```

My preview code.

```swift
#if DEBUG
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView (viewModel: LoginViewModel()).environment(\.verticalSizeClass, .regular)
    }
}
#endif
```

When I put the custom style inside the same file as the view. The preview is ok.
But when I moved the custom style in it's own file (in the purpose of reusing it in the whole app). The preview is throwing error.

```
Compiling failed: type 'Any' has no member 'leading'
```

Do I have to add something in the `LoginView_Previews` to make it load in preview? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is due to conflict with built-in `DefaultButtonStyle`, so name your somehow differently, like

```
struct MyDefaultButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    // .. other code

...

Button(action: { self.viewModel.login() }) {
  Text("Sign In")
    .font(.headline)
}
.buttonStyle(MyDefaultButtonStyle())
```